# recordsTotal, recordsFiltered explanation Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm reading datatable doc's but i can't find an answer. My question is:

I have a table with 10.000 rows. I do a search by state and result is 3000 rows. From 3000 rows, i'll show 20 per page.

"recordsTotal": what value should be in here?,
"recordsFiltered": what value should be in here?,

If recordsTotal value must be 10.000, can i hide this value if is not interesting?

Comment: recordsTotal will be 3000.

Comment: @BasantaMatia thank you, and "recordsFiltered"?

Answer (score 36):

From [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data):

> `recordsTotal`
>
> Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
>
> `recordsFiltered`
>
> Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data).

Your response should be:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 10000,
    "recordsFiltered": 3000,
    "data": [
       // ... skipped 20 records ...
    ]
}
```

I believe `recordsTotal` is only used for informational panel `Showing 1 to 20 of 3000 entries (filtered from 10000 total entries)`. If you're not using informational panel, you don't have to return `recordsTotal` property.

Property `recordsFiltered` is also used by jQuery DataTables to calculate number of pages required to display your dataset.

See [Server-side - Returned data](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) for more information.

Comment: Humm...i believe recordsTotal in my case is just waste of processing...why check all records from a table each time i reload page or use pagination?

Comment: @MarceloÁgil, I agree. If you're not displaying that info to user or not using that anywhere in the front-end script, there is no point to retrieve it. However if you use third-party libraries for server-side processing, they will calculate totals for you.

Comment: Just a note, if you are using server-side-processing class provided by dadatable guys, when counting recordsTotal, it will count `primaryKey`. So even if you have 20 entries returned, but `primaryKey` field is `null` in 19 entries, recordsTotal will be 1