# Datatable plugin not work properly in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using datatable in a new MVC ASP.NET core project.
I want to using server side option to load record in my table.
This is my html code:

```
                <table id="datatableClienti" class="table table-striped dt-responsive nowrap w-100">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RagioneSociale)</th>
                        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contatto)</th>
                        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Citta)</th>
                        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Provincia)</th>
                        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</th>                            
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                      
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and this script:

```
@section scripts {
<script src="~/js/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-responsive-bs5/js/responsive.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-buttons-bs5/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatableClienti').DataTable(
        {
            serverSide: "true",
            ajax: {
                    url: "/Cliente/Getlist",
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json"
                    },
                    columns: [
                                {data:"ragioneSociale","name":"RagioneSociale"},
                                { data: "contatto", "name": "Contatto" },
                                { data: "citta", "name": "Citta" },
                                { data: "provincia", "name": "Provincia" },
                                { data: "email", "name": "Email" }
                            ],                        
                    order:[0,"asc"],
            lengthChange: true,                    
                dom: '<"container-fluid"<"row"<"col"B><"col"l><"col"f>>>rtip',
                dom: '<"dt-buttons"Bf><"clear">lirtip',
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Nuovo',
                    className: 'text-info'
                        },
                    'searchPanes','copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
                language:
                    {
                        url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.4/i18n/it-IT.json"
                    },
                keys: true

               
        });            
    });
    
</script>
```

This is code in MVC controller to return JSON data:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetList()
    {           

        List<Cliente> emplist = new List<Cliente>();

        emplist = _context.Clienti.ToList<Cliente>();            

        return Json(new {data= emplist});
    }
```

Plugin work and format table well but **all** record was showed **without paging** also if there is a paging control.
[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: How many entries are there in the `emplist` ?

Comment: `return Json(new {data= emplist});` - no paging information, i have no clue how datatable should work out the number of pages and current page number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recordsTotal, recordsFiltered explanation Jquery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161353/recordstotal-recordsfiltered-explanation-jquery-datatable)

Comment: Just to add: unless you have so much data that it performs poorly when loading & rendering in the browser, maybe you don't even need `serverSide: true`. Keep it simple, and let DataTables do the pagination, filtering and sorting for you.